# floating point number issue in Ruby

Tags: ruby

is this a ruby bug or a problem in  my system .
i'm using ubuntu

```
 moo@jmj uni (master) $ ruby -v
    ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-linux]
    moo@jmj uni (master) $ ^C
    moo@jmj uni (master) $ irb
    2.1.2 :001 > 0.05 +0.01
     => 0.060000000000000005 
    2.1.2 :002 >
```

Comment: It's neither. This is how floating point arithmetics works.

Comment: It's primarily for Java, but explains the problem in great detail, check: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: what that means? 0.05 +0.01 => 0.060000000000000005  but  0.03 +0.01
 => 0.04

Comment: You might want to read about [accuracy problems with floating point number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems). To avoid problems like this, use [BigDecimal](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.1/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html).